# c# asp.net map middleware for route

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm implementing some middleWare which I only want to run on a specific route

```
/api
```

There are some other middleware's which always should run, some before and some after the api specific middleware. My code in Startup.cs :

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseIdentity();
//some more middleware is added here

//my own middleware which should only run for routes at /api
app.UseCookieAuthMiddleware();

//some more middleware is added here
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseKendo(env);
```

The order of loading the middleware is important so I want to keep this order.
`app.UseCookieAuthMiddleware();` should only run on urls which start with /api e.g. `"/api, /api/test, /api?test"`. 
I saw app.Map was an option but how does one make sure all the other middleware's after app.Map are added to.

edit: example on when map skips the lines below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   app.UseIdentity();
   //some more middleware is added here
   app.Map("/api", HandleApiRoutes);


   //lines below are skipped ONLY when map is used.
   //some more middleware should be added here 
   app.UseKendo(env);
}


private static void HandleApiRoutes(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthMiddleware();
}
```

My middleware:

```
public class CookieCheckMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CookieCheckMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Middleware is called" );

        //Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline this._next(context) is called no errors.
        return this._next(context);
    }
}

public static class CookieCheckMiddleWareMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCookieAuthMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CookieCheckMiddleWare>();
    }
}
```

I can simply solve the problem by always running the middleware and do a check in the middleware.invore to check if the reques url is like "/api":

```
  public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
       var url = context.Request.Path.Value.ToString();
       var split = url.Split('/');
       if (split[1] == "api") //should do a extra check to allow /api?something
       {
          //middleware functions
       }
  }
```

But I like to know how to propperly use the map function.

Comment: I deleted original answer and posted a new one